# How to run localhost in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, localhost, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a simple api rest in python using flask and sqlalchemy. I install both successfully. I also install postman to test the code. I make a simple script in python in order to check if localhost is running. The code is this one:

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

#init app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def get():
return jsonfy({'msg': 'Server running'})

#run server
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

In postman I type the following url in the request: localhost:5000.

After send the request I watch the following messages:

Could not get any response

There was an error connecting to http:localhost:5000.

I type this url in a web browser and the message is the same.

I know the error is due to I haven't the server up. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What message do you get when you start the server with ```python <name_of_your_script>.py```

Comment: The message is the following: from flask_sql_alchemy import SQLAlchemy ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sql_alchemy'

Answer (score 1):

have you configured flask? 
if not, click cntrl + shift + a 
=> then go to edit configuration and set flask to run when started.
it will suppose to let you after that to run it. (just assume you not running)
configuration seems to be okay but didn't tested. 
look at the picture for the flask server (you probably don't have it so add it at the plus

[image]

Comment: You mentioned click cntrl + shift + a. I tried it but I didn't watch anything. How can I watch the screenshot above? Thanks

Comment: hey axmug,
after you do it. write edit (then you will see edit configuarion and click on it :))
it will solve your case

Comment: I know what happens but I don't know how to fix it. If I comment second and third lines, that is, from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy and
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow it works. How can I run it with both lines uncommented?

Comment: I fixed the error. The problem was I didn't install neither sqlalhemy nor marshmallow. I did it using pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy and pip3 install flask_marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

use:
return jsonify({'msg': 'Server running'})
instead of:
return jsonfy({'msg': 'Server running'})

Answer (score 0):

This one is working

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

#init app
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def get():
    return jsonify({'msg': 'Server running'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

it's showing this in Postman
[image]

Comment: How did you do it? If I comment second and third lines, that is, from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy and from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow it works.It means that I haven't neither sqlalchemy and marshmallow correctly installed. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I fixed the problem installing sql_alchemy and marshmallow using the following commands: pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy and pip3 install flask_marshmallow